# float casting *= equations in php

Tags: php, casting, operators

Currently using PHP 8.1, I hit fatal errors whenever I do a formulae such as String * Float. Ok, so I just fix it by float casting it, and it's solved.

But I noticed another issue, is that float casting doesn't work when we use symbols such as *= and +=

Refer below example

```
$a = "";
$b = "2";
//first way
(float) $a *= (float) $b; //fatal error, unsupported operand String * float
//second way
$a = (float) $a * (float) $b; //works
```

I assume that the first clause results to

```
(float) $a = $a * (float) $b;
```

which causes the error.

Is there anyway to solve this or must it always be done the second way? Assuming I can't control what is $a (I can't float cast it in advance).

Thanks

Comment: The first way is apparently interpreted as `(float) ($a *= (float) $b); `. It technically does have a value, as `$something_else = (float) ($a *= (float) $b);` is possible. In contrast, it does not make sense to interpret it as e.g. `( (float) $a) = $something`, because while you can assign to `$a`, you can't assign to `((float) $a)`; it is not a variable.

Comment: Why are you defining the variables as string if they are numeric ?  define them as **$a=0;*** and **$b=2;**

Comment: @RohitGupta it's just a test case. As said in my last sentence, assuming that I can't control what is $a, how can i fix this without going to the second way.